# Taper Object Cannot Alter Curve Start?

Tags: objects

I'm trying to make use of curves to animate a stroke, specifically a cartoon-ish "wind" effect, by animating the "bulge" shown in the taper object from left to right (as indicated by the arrow).

My problem is that no matter how much I twiddle the control points for the controlling Taper object, I cannot get the very beginning of the curve to act with a zero diameter (shown circled) – which apparently is not a problem for the end of the curve.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Probably caused by the very beginning (left) of the taper object. You can see it's fairly high there.

Comment: Oh man, thanks so much! That's what I get for following EVERY SINGLE Youtube tutorial out there about "Grow a curve"! They ALWAYS say to put that point there, so I thought it was necessary to, like, set the y-extents for the calculation...